# SSH into Pi always fails on first attempt

Tags: ssh

I use PuTTY and a Wi-Fi dongle to SSH into my Pi. It ALWAYS times out on the first attempt and then when I close PuTTY and re-open it, I can SSH into the Pi.

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Tom"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 30:46:9A:A2:59:D6
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=85/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: do you mean first attempt after booting? wait a little longer after booting maybe?

Comment: maybe if you posted the session log?

Comment: @JaromandaX It doesn't matter how long I wait. I could wait 10 minutes and I cant ssh into it first attempt.

JayEye how do i get the session log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pi4,I use this command:

```
 sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you got power saving mode enabled in your WiFi dongle.

You can check it in `sudo iwconfig` and turn it off: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` , where `wlan0` is your wifi card name in `iwconfig` list.

If it doesn't help tell us more about your WiFi dongle. Post `iwconfig` and `lsusb` by editing your post.

@Edit:
Here was similar issue and [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7760/42034) helped:

Comment: I updated the post with info. When i tried running the power off command I got SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted. And I ran it as sudo

Comment: Thanks for update. Here someone had similar issue with the same chipset and this post helped: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7760/42034 .