# How to set up WiFi with Raspbian "wheezy"

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have been trying to setup up WiFi with my Raspberry Pi Model A (meaning I don't have a internet connection currently), running Raspbian 2013. I have tried several things to setup my WiFi but none of them worked:

The manual approach:

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis

This gave me boot errors, and I never was able to connect to the internet.

The GUI approach:

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-raspbian

My network flag is WEP, and it has a pass-phrase but `wpa_config` never asked for one and I was unable to connect.

I have tried several other different approaches but they all led down to these 2 basic approaches...

I am using a Tenda USB WiFi adapter that *is* compatible with my Pi, and my network is a WEP network with a password. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This is what I used: http://www.ronnutter.com/raspberry-pi-adding-wifi-wpawpa2-using-wpa_cli/ . PS it would be helpful if you posted the contents `/etc/network/interfaces` you used in the manual approach

Comment: @Gerben Thank you for your suggestion, I figured my issue, thanks though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically reconnect WiFi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi)

Comment: @coding_corgi could you please post your solution as an answer if you figured out your problem?

Comment: @coding_corgi Could you please post your solution as an answer? We are trying to get this site up to par and that will help!

Answer (score 3):

Both those approaches you've linked are WPA based. If your network really is WEP, it's a slightly different process. Try editing the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file and adding something like this:

```
network={
    ssid="static-wep-test"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    wep_key0="abcde"
    wep_key1=0102030405
    wep_tx_keyidx=0
    priority=5
}
```

If that doesn't work you can try configuring it manually from the command line with the iwconfig utility:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "MyNetwork" key "s:password"
```

Drop the "s:" if your WEP key is a hexadecimal code rather than a string password. (In the wpa_supplicant example use "" for a password and without for a hexadecimal code.)

Comment: I had the same issue, however, if you're using a "string" for your key (rather than hex) you can simply change /etc/network/interfaces to the following (you don't need to bother with the wpa_supplicant at all) 

`auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid your-SSID
wireless-key s:yourpasswordstring`