# Setting up Raspbian and WiFi on a private network

Tags: networking, wifi, security

I just got raspbian installed on my SD card and am trying to get my Pi on my network. It's protected with WPA2 Personal.

I opened up the gui network connect and added a new network with the proper SSID, security and password. However, the Pi won't connect. All I'm getting as the status is "Scanning" and the last message being "WPS-AP-AVAILABLE-AUTH".

Comment: Are you scanning first, then selecting your network from the scan results and typing the password?

Comment: Disable the security measures **temporarily** and see if it works. Does `iwconfig` produce anything?

Comment: I can't simply scan because I have a hidden SSID. I could try removing the security temporarily but that would be a last resort as I would have to reconfigure a lot of devices on my network.

Comment: Try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9750/894

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your network block in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

scan_ssid=1

GUI does not add it for hidden networks. After verifying all my other settings and still not connecting, I added this line, did a sudo ifdown wlan0 then sudo ifup wlan0 and it connected and got an IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try ditching the gui and try via command line
http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/

Comment: You should include the essential parts of the link in this answer to avoid [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way I know is to set up WiFi via command line, in other words not GUI. This is how I have done it and it's working flawlessly:

Make sure /etc/network/interfaces contain the following:

```
$sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up wpa_supplicant -B w -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
iface default inet dhcp
```

Edit the following file:

```
$sudo more /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="YOURSSID"
psk="YOURPASSWORD"

# Protocol type can be: RSN (for WP2) and WPA (for WPA1)
proto=WPA

# Key management type can be: WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP (Pre-Shared or Enterprise)
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# Pairwise can be CCMP or TKIP (for WPA2 or WPA1)
pairwise=TKIP

#Authorization option should be OPEN for both WPA1/WPA2 (in less commonly used are SHARED and LEAP)
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

I have also found out that some WiFi-dongles go into sleep-mode after about 6 hours.
To that I found the following solution:

Edit the file:

```
$sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf

# Disable power saving
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=1 rtw_ips_mode=1
```