# Trying to understand Auto reconnect WIFI method

Tags: networking, wifi

Iv'e found this method of reconnecting the WIFI dongle from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi) , but want to be clear on how it works, before I try and implement it.

> 1) Go to `/etc/ifplugd/action.d/` and rename the **ifupdown** file to
>   **ifupdown.original**,
>  2)Then do: `cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh ./ifupdown` 
> 3) Finally: `sudo reboot`

1) When is `/etc/ifplugd/action.d/ifupdown` called ?
2) What does the script `/etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh` essentially do in laymens terms, it looks pretty complex to me; and when is it called too.
3) Could doing steps 1 to 3 cause any other unforeseen problems that would lock me out (upset the WIFI) of my headless, hard to reach PI?