# Can't get wifi working in non-gui environment

Tags: wifi

I'm having trouble getting wifi working on my new RPi2. It works fine when I run X and use wpa_gui, but it's not working on the console, even when using the configuration saved by wpa_gui.

The main difference between the two is that, when wpa_gui runs the show, DHCP works and gets an IP address, and the route table gets a couple of entries, whereas on the console neither happens. Even if I force a static IP, the route table is still empty and wifi still doesn't work.

Some info about my hardware:

- `lsusb` reports `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter`
- `lsmod` lists `8192cu` installed, which I believe is the correct driver for this chipset.

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YYYYY"
    psk="xxxxxxxx"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

The output of `iwconfig` is identical in both X and console environments:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"YYYYY"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/100  Signal level=45/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

There are some slight differences in the processes running: under X there are some extra DBus-related processes running, and they run as user `pi`, whereas the one that is running in the console is run as user `messagebus` (104) though curiously this name is not displayed by `ps` even though it is in `/etc/passwd`.

Console listing (relevant processes):

```
root      1709     1  0 22:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i wlan0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1759     1  0 22:56 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -W -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
root      1793     1  0 22:56 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_cli -B -P /var/run/wpa_action.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant -a /sbin/wpa_action
104       2100     1  0 22:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
root      2229     1  0 22:58 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0
```

X listing:

```
root      1709     1  0 02:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i wlan0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1759     1  0 02:07 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -W -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
root      1793     1  0 02:07 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_cli -B -P /var/run/wpa_action.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant -a /sbin/wpa_action
104       2100     1  0 02:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
pi        2361  2338  0 02:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/ck-launch-session /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
pi        2366     1  0 02:16 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
pi        2367     1  0 02:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
pi        2417     1  1 02:17 tty1     00:00:01 /usr/sbin/wpa_gui
root      2510     1  0 02:17 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0
```

Just thinking about it as I type this - could it be a permissions issue around the `pi` and `messagebus` users that's causing something in the network initialisation process (eg. DHCP) to fail in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another example of why I think `NetworkManager` is a nasty piece of business for simple, single connection systems like most people would use on a home LAN.

Getting connected manually is really only a matter of a few commands, but to test this you first must disable NetworkManager or it will screw with you.

```
sudo service NetworkManager stop
```

Hopefully it stays that way.  I usually just remove it from the system completely, but that is probably not good general advice --  it presumably works for most people most of the time.

Now make sure `dhclient` isn't running.

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

There won't be any output, but `ps -C dhclient` should now show nothing.  To actually connect:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This will block on the terminal, which is fine for now because you want to see what happens.  To send it straight to background instead, add `-B`.  It is normal for it to report some minor errors/warnings.

From another terminal:

```
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

This should take a moment and end with you receiving a lease and a local IP address.  If that happens, you're online.  If it works, you can put those commands in a script.  With pis, as mentioned, I just uninstall `NetworkManager` (and its even uglier cousin, `ifplugd`) and do a simple check at boot:

```
if [[ -n "$(ip link | grep wlan)" ]]; then
# Connect wifi if an adapter is connected.
    ip link set wlan0 up
    # `wpa_supplicant` MUST be started `-B`
    wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    dhclient -nw wlan0
else
# Connect ethernet.
    ip link set eth0 up
    dhclient -nw wlan0
fi
```

Not as flexible as NM but never fails and is hassle-free.  There's a somewhat zanier version of this [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi/5121#5121).

Comment: Thanks heaps! This worked, although I never had `NetworkManager` installed to begin with, so I'm still not sure what the issue was. (`ifplugd` perhaps?) Anyway, I ended up installing `wicd-curses`, which worked too and was dead easy.