# Setting up wifi on network with no passkey

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have a rasPi-2B, and when I successfully set up the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file when I was at my house at my college. But, now that I am home for for spring break, I can't get the wifi to work in the same way.

The router here does not have a password set up, so I tried editing the wpa file to have the `ssid= the ssid` and I had the `psk=""`. That did not work, so I tried `psk=`, which did not work either. I am unsure what to try.

I also was unsure if the space in the ssid is the issue, if I am supposed to place underscores in the spaces.

EDIT: the content of my interfaces file->

```
auto wlan
iface wlan inet dhcp
    wireless-essid My SS ID


auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: If the network is unencrypted don't use `wpa_supplicant` at all.

Comment: @goldilocks how do I set it up to auto connect to my router without wpa-supplicant

Comment: I've added an answer, but if you want to manual configure it for both networks (home and school) you should ask how to do that on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the normal configuration methods, but [based on this](http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/WL:Wifi_Configuration#Open) it looks like you want an entry like this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wireless-essid YOUR_SSID_GOES_HERE
```

Of course, you probably want to keep the existing listing you have for school -- have a look at [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/wifi-setup-for-multiple-networks), which is slightly different but similar circumstances.  One of the answers also suggests the use of `wicd-curses`, which might make all this easier.

If you just want to try to connect temporarily, you could use [my method here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28691/cant-get-wifi-working-in-non-gui-environment/28695#28695) but use `iwconfig` instread of `wpa_supplicant`:

```
service NetworkManager stop
ip link set wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid YOUR_ESSID
dhclient -v wlan0
```

All that has to be done `sudo`.

Comment: I tried this, but I still cannot connect

Comment: My SSID is three words, with spaces. I don't know if this would effect how I enter it.

Comment: try surrounding ESSID with single quotation marks or double quotation marks. 'name of AP' or "name of AP" If that doesn't work, there are some other possible ways to encode a space but I'm not sure what iwconfig will accept.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that yesterday.  You can also pass spaces this way: `one\ two\ three` but `"one two three"` should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

I always start x and just use wpa_gui.

Comment: Unlikely to work if the network does not use WPA encryption, which requires a password.  Hence, if this is a network with no password -- as described in the question -- it is not WPA encrypted.