# could not get status from wpa_supplicant signal 15 received

Tags: wifi, wpa

I'm getting following message inside of `wpa_gui`:

```
Status: Could not get status from wpa_supplicant
Last Message: -signal 15 received
```

What is `signal 15`? I tried clicking on `Disconnect` & `Connect`, but nothing seems to be working for me other then `Menu` -> `Shutdown` -> `Reboot`.

Is there a service I can restart, so I don't have to rebooting my Raspberry?

Comment: Signal 15 is SIGTERM, but I guess that doesn't help you much.  It's a polite way of asking a process to stop, but it can be ignored.   Have you tried restarting `wpa_gui`?   You could also try `service NetworkManager restart`...

Comment: I tried restarting `wpa_gui` that did not help, but I got new `Status: Could not get status from wpa_supplicant`, and `service NetworkManager restart` returns `NetworkManager: unrecognized service`

Comment: Sorry -- Raspbian doesn't use that by default and it is probably for the best. How about `service networking restart`?    I can't promise anything but it is worth a try.

Comment: _that_ i tried, however that did not help me resolve my question( (still same `Status: Could not get status from wpa_supplicant`)

Comment: Hmmm.  In order `sudo service networking stop` (ignore it if it won't), `sudo killall -9 wpa_supplicant`, `sudo service networking start`.

Comment: `wpa_supplicant` isn't running according to `ps` output and `sudo service networking stop` stops networking service without any problem too.

Comment: Once you have networking stopped, `wpa_gui` stopped, and there are no `wpa_supplicant` instances running, [try this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28691/cant-get-wifi-working-in-non-gui-environment/28695#28695) (you can ignore the beginning bit about NetworkManager).

Comment: I checked for `wpa_supplicant` before issuing `sudo service networking stop`, I guess after `signal 15` it's pretty much gone and from link that you provided, I found issuing `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` would get `wpa_supplicant` back)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it turned out that the input power to the Raspberry was too low. Source transformer had an output of 700mA (and 5.5v of course, since it is USB). I had connected via usb a TP Link device for the wifi connection and USB mouse and keyboard via a hub on the other USB port. That was (I guess) above the 700mA.
I replace the transformer with a different one that have 1A output and I can use at the same time the usb hub and the TP link access point without the annoying signal 15 popping up.
I hope it helps

Comment: I've tried @work w/ 850ma and home w/ 1A and got same thing(

Comment: I am using the Power Adapter that comes with the [Canakit Complete Starter Kit](http://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-starter-kit.html) and I'm having the same issue.