# How to setup Network Manager on Raspbian

Tags: networking, raspbian-wheezy

Is it possible to get Network Manager working on Raspbian? It's easy to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

but I couldn't get it to manage any of my connections. Unfortunately, it looks like only a old version of NM is available in the Debian repo.

Comment: If you want some graphical interface to manage network connections, try `wicd-curses`. http://blog.ubidots.com/setup-wifi-on-raspberry-pi-using-wicd provides a tutorial.

Comment: Try to purge the packages openresolv and dhcpcd5. I did it and NM started working without issues.

Answer (score 35):

I have found how to get NetworkManager (and systemd-resolved) working on **Raspbian 9** (Stretch). NetworkManager is very useful when you need to manage multiple VPN connections with split DNS, wifi networks and other advanced network settings directly from the Pixel Desktop.

Here is how to do it:

1. Install the needed packages with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome openvpn \
   openvpn-systemd-resolved network-manager-openvpn \
   network-manager-openvpn-gnome
   ```
2. Remove unneded packages:

   ```
   sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5
   ```
3. Replace /etc/resolv.conf with a symlink to /lib/systemd/resolv.conf:

   (do **not** execute this command on Raspbian 10, it will break your DNS)

   ```
   [only for Raspbian 9, not 10]
   sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
4. Now go to the top of your screen and reconfigure the panel:

   1. Open "Panel Settings"
   2. In "Panel Applets" remove the "Wireless & Wired Network" item.
   3. The network manager applet should appear after a **reboot**.

Comment: Thank you! The purge step was vital. Without that, nmcli showed all my devices as "unavailable" and it couldn't control them.

Comment: You don't actually need `openvpn`.

Comment: I had a problem where my raspberry wouldn't connect to the internet through Ethernet. I had to undo step 3 (I kept backup), and then everything worked perfectly - Thanks

Comment: I plugged my laptop (Ubuntu 14) to my RPi 3 (Raspbian Stretch) via ssh over an Ethernet cable.

Doing nmcli dev wifi on the laptop gives me a whole bunch of networks. Typing the same command on the R Pi gives me no network at all. I went through the steps you decribed (without error message or anything suspicious along the way)... but nmcli still doens't detect anything. Any idea why? Could it have to do with the ethernet connection?

Comment: @luke The purge step isn't vital at all. NetworkManager just doesn't touch managed devices (like those configured in /etc/interfaces)

Comment: This answer would be better without step 3.  I've just tested it on a fresh Raspbian Buster install (September 2019 version) on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.   Step 3 is redundant and breaks the DNS.

Comment: How do I reverse step 3? These steps broke my ethernet connection.

Comment: I've only done step 1 and step 2, restarted and now the ethernet connection is not working at all, how to fix that?

Comment: To reverse step 3, delete the link: `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: It seems that the purge is the key line. I was having issues and once I purged these two packages the NM started working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This page ranks quite highly in search results for people looking for networking help on Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately, the steps detailed here are out-of-date as of Feb 2020.

At that point in time, to get Network Manager handling wifi on current Pi OS:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Check `/etc/network/interfaces` - it should be empty except for an include from `/etc/network/interfaces.d`. Now edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and add:

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dhcp=internal

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Restart, and you should have Network Manager in your menu bar, handling the wifi interface.

I've a few more details of what I did to make this work in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jjsanderson/ab2407ab5fd07feb2bc5e681b14a537a), including an alternative approach using a configuration file in `/boot`.

Unfortunately, I can't confirm that any of this still works as I no longer have access to the corporate network which requires Network Manager. But comments on the gist suggest that it's worked for at least some others. Good luck!

Comment: I had been on your gist some few minutes ago. Now I find you here. Thanks for writing the gist and reporting on SE.

Comment: Another approach that may be of interest is `systemd-networkd`; there's a [comprehensive Q&A on how to set that up here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking) for Raspberry Pi. It also works for those that run "headless" - or the "Lite" version of the distro.

Comment: You are truly my lord and saviour =). Switching over to `NetworkManager` is probably the easiest way to get WiFi settings working in GUI, if using Gnome.

Comment: This is the answer for Raspbian 10. Thanks!

Comment: And Raspbian 11

Comment: I got it working, the network manager connects to my LTE module but I have no internet. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

Try using `wicd`:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Wicd is a network manager application (wireless and wired), it a good alternative to Network Manager

Comment: It would be helpful to at least try to explain how `wicd` is going to help the OP. Feel free to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9750/894  WICD curses exaplined

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, the OP asked how to install NetworkManager (not "a network manager") on Raspbian. `wicd` presents an easy TUI for managing networking, but so does `nmtui` that comes with NetworkManager. I don't see how acknowledging that `wicd` can be used for managing networks relates to the question of how to install `NetworkManager`.

Comment: WICD does not work properly on raspbian Stretch. It continually doesn't bring the WLAN back up after disconnection saying that you have to "manually do it" making it useless. Development seems to have been abandoned as there haven't been updates for years.

Comment: wicd is still a python2 programm - don't use it until there is a python3 port

Answer (score 3):

Chien's [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120146/149586) will create a non persistent change and `dhcpcd` will restart after after reboot. The clash will give the device two IPs per interface.

A persistent solution would be:

```bash
sudo apt install network-manager
# for gui systems "sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome"
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service 
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today (2023), Raspberry Pi OS (former Raspbian) comes with NetworkManager support, but it is disabled by default. To enable, run those commands:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome

# This command will enable NetworkManager, without needing to jump through GUI:
sudo raspi-config nonint do_netconf 2
sudo reboot
```

After reboot (for GUI), NetworkManager will be used.

And `nmcli` will work as expected, e.g. `nmcli dev wifi` will scan and list all visible WiFi APs.

Comment: Seems the service has been renamed to `NetworkManager`, for when it comes time to start/restart/stop it.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo service dhcpcd stop 
sudo service network-manager restart
```