# How to configure network-manager

Tags: raspbian, networking, internet, gui, raspi-config

I'm new to rpi but not new to debian. A bit frustrated trying to find answers online. Hoping someone can answer some questions for me:

What's the default raspbian network manager called?

How do I disable it completely?

How can I get network-manager to act as my network manager and show up in my icon dock?

I installed network-manager already and did $(systemctl enable NetworkManager.service) but there's no apparent graphical interface available and I don't know how to disable the current wifi manager.

```
    $ uname -a 

    Linux 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

.

```
    $ lsb_release -a

    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Raspbian
    Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
    Release:    8.0
    Codename:   jessie
```

This post wasn't so helpful: [How to setup Network Manager on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/how-to-setup-network-manager-on-raspbian)

Any help would be great!

Cheers

Comment: Could you explain why do you need `network-manager` or Raspbian? Maybe you're trying to work around a problem that can be solved differently.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also trying to get rid of the default network manager, since I use Network Manager for my managing my VPN and broadband connections. WiFi connections are still being managed by the default one, which is a bit of a pain.