# Connect to Group Network via Bluetooth Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, ssh, bluetooth, raspbian-stretch, remote

I want to do SSH from my Macbook Air to my Raspberry Pi 3 via bluetooth. I'm using macOS Sierra version 10.12.1 and Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ 2017 with the latest version of 
RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP (released on 2018-06-27 on this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). First, I made sure to update and upgrade my Raspberry Pi system by running:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

`sudo apt-get update`.

Then I installed bluez, bluetooth, and blueman:

`sudo apt-get install bluez`

`sudo apt-get bluetooth --fix-missing`

`sudo apt-get blueman --fix-missing`.

I rebooted my Raspberry Pi. Then I went to "System Preferences" and selected "Bluetooth" on my MacBook Air. I searched for "raspberrypi" and paired with the device. Then, on my Raspberry Pi I went to "Preferences" and selected "Bluetooth Manager". When I selected "Connect to: Group Network" and clicked "Next", it said "Device added successfully, but failed to connect". I want the device to be added and connected successfully as shown in Andrew Mulholland's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ac0wc-f9HI .

How do I solve this problem?

UPDATE: The reason appears to be: "Connection Failed: The name org.freedesktop.Networkmanager was not provided by any service files". I can connect to my Macbook Air as "Audio Source" but not "Group Network".

Comment: I solved it. I just installed network manager on my Raspberry Pi. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/how-to-setup-network-manager-on-raspbian

Comment: Please make your comment an answer and accept it. This finishes the question and it will no more pop up.

Comment: I actually answered my own question but because it was brief, it was automatically placed as comment by StackExchange. Should I make it unnecessarily long to be accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I just installed network manager on my Raspberry Pi.

Reference:
[How to setup Network Manager on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/how-to-setup-network-manager-on-raspbian)