# Why does my pi disconnect from the internet after leaving it on for a day?

Tags: wifi, internet

I have recently been having a problem where I leave my raspberry pi on connected to the internet as I am running an a apache server on it and when I come back to the Raspberry Pi about a day later the dongle isn't flashing blue like it usually does. I go to the wpa_gui and it says as the status 'Could not get status from spa_supplicant'. I tried taking out the dongle half way and then pushing it back in. This seems to get it working again but I had it working before where I could just leave it and it would stay connected to the internet. Does anyone have any ideas what I could do to stop it disconnecting?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? `/var/log/udev` and `/var/log/dmesg` might be good places to start.

Comment: what do i look for inside the dmesg?

Comment: I have changed the usb ports of the dongle to see what happens because before it all started to happen I seem to remember that i had my dongle on the bottom usb port and the usb hub on the top one.

Comment: It might also me a problem with your router. You should look into your router settings and see if it refreshes the router on a 24 hr basis for example.

Comment: Actually this issue drove me crazy for weeks.  It turned out I hadn't installed proper drivers for the dongle I choose.  I just double checked.. Mines been up now 202 days, so I think the problem is solved... Originally I would get 12-36 hours before I couldn't ssh in anymore. Google the dongle's model number.

Comment: great you got it sorted. Please add your solution as an answer with as much details regarding the driver versions and how you identified/updated them when you get the chance.

Comment: I think I had a dongle like that -- at first it used to disconnect regularly and I [used this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5121/5538).  Then at one point I noticed the blue light, which previously blinked slowly, stayed steady, and connecting without that script was fine.  My guess is the driver was upgraded, but I never looked into that.

Comment: WRT logs you want to try and pinpoint when the connection went down and look in `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` (which contains everything by default on Raspbian) around that time for anything that is obviously a wifi device failure.

Comment: I think I have got it working again, I did what i said in the comment yesterday and it has been over 24 hours and i haven't had to take out the dongle and put it back in yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your wifi dongle entered in power saving mode, toit, you have to add "wireless-power off" in your "interfaces" file

1/ Type

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

2/ Add at the end of file

```
wireless-power off
```

3/ Reboot by typing :

```
sudo reboot
```