# How to recover when WiFi drops?

Tags: networking, wifi

My RPis do not reconnect back to a WiFi AP when the signal temporarily vanishes (during the reboot of the AP for instance). A hard reboot (power off/on) is the only solution for those which are headless and WiFi only.

There have been [numerous](http://weworkweplay.com/play/rebooting-the-raspberry-pi-when-it-loses-wireless-connection-wifi/) [workarounds](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/test-and-configure#fixing-wifi-dropout-issues) over the years, but no real fix. Is this something which has been fixed today?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5341/14032 solution works out pretty well for me.

Comment: `dhcpcd` should handle this automatically.

Comment: It [was installed on my system](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38836/6123) but did not help (though it was not configured and was breaking DNS resolving, per the linked question)