# How to prevent /etc/resolv.conf from being overwritten?

Tags: networking, dns

I use a static IP for my RPi:

```
root@rpi2:/etc# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.254
        wpa-essid myssid
        wpa-psk mykey
        dns-nameservers 192.156.0.254
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` (which is a plain file, not a link) gets rewritten at each reboot with

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I do not even have `resolvconf` installed!

```
root@rpi2:~# aptitude search resolvconf
p   resolvconf  - name server information handler
```

How can I disable this overwriting? (short of `chattr +i` which is an ugly hack)

Comment: I'm still confused by what exactly the thing is (the old method appears to mostly works for me...), but apparently there is some new way to configure the internet, see [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/10590). Which version of raspbian are you using?

Comment: @Wilf: this is interesting - I saw both ways but did not know that the supplicant one is the way to go forward. As for my question, please see my answer - I found the issue (which is IMHO a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and input a line starting with `supersede`. This line makes sure that only the supplied list of values for `domain-name-servers` on it's right will be written inside  `/etc/resolv.conf` when writing event happens.

Example:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1, ::1;
```

Comment: This doesn't work on all RPI's... I wonder why?

Comment: If this method does not work first edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` and dissable insert into a file  using this command: `chattr -V +i /etc/resolv.conf`. To revert back use the command: `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf`. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860655/resolv-conf-gets-re-written-on-reboot#answer-58401019)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I found the issue. `/bin/dhcpcd` was still running despite no interfaces being configured via DHCP. The culprit is `dhcpcd5`.

Removing the package helped (and, surprise, something called `openresolv` was included)

```
root@rpi2:~# aptitude purge dhcpcd5
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dhcpcd5{p} openresolv{u}
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` is not overwritten anymore.

Comment: With respect this is like solving a rattling noise problem in a car by removing the spare. `dhcpcd` is included in all recent releases of Raspbian, and removing it will break other features. If you don't want to use it you should disable in `systemd`. There is nothing wrong with configuring your Pi the old way, but you can set static with `dhcpcd`.

Comment: @Milliways: could you please elaborate on *break other features*? `dhcpd` was installed on my system but a `dhcpd.conf` was not even present.

Comment: `dhcpcd` is a complex program, and not without its problems. I think the Foundation adopted it because it automates networking (particularly WiFi) and allows easy setup from GUI. (Current GUI WiFi setup requires it.) I was initially not keen, but the fact that it allows `zeroconf` over link-local and thus `ssh` is a plus. It automatically handles changing network conditions without the complexity of wpa-roam. Lastly it is highly configurable, even if the documentation is a bit cryptic and technical. See the following for overview and read the man.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing dhcpcd and breaking a bunch of stuff, you *could* configure /etc/dhcpcd.conf (and probably /etc/init.d/dnsmasq) with your DNS information...

Just sayin'

Comment: On my setup of Raspbian GNU/Linux 10, adding the line `resolvconf=NO` to the file `/etc/resolvconf.conf` fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simple as putting it's permissions to read-only.

```
sudo chmod 440 /etc/resolv.conf
```

But I would suggest to check again what is causing your `resolv.conf` to be overwritten as setting it to read-only may cause some other unexpected things.

Comment: *But I would suggest to check again what is causing your resolv.conf to be overwritten* - this is the essence of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot) for Unix. The solution does not require to remove the `dhcpd5` package.

However, I have not yet figured out where the config files for dhcpd are hiding on my Pi/Jessie. 
There are several suggestions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf#Modify_the_dhcpcd_config), I'll try the one where you add fixed DNS addresses at the end of the /etc/dhcpcd.conf.

Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable the service resolved by entering:
`sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: You may want to use `mask` there instead of `disable` as this is something that is bound to be "required" by some other service (which implicitly enables it even if it was previously disabled).