# Does (raspbian) automatically renew DHCP lease when there is a problem?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-2, dhcp

For some reason my pi 2b Doesn't renew it's DHCP lease when something goes wrong.
I have to restart it or manually reconnect to the wifi.
I don't like doing that because it's supposed to be a 'headless server'.

[image: pi without lease]

Is there some setting that I could change that does this automatically or do I have to write something that does this?

Comment: *"For some reason my pi 2b Doesn't renew it's DHCP lease when something goes wrong."* -> That assumes the correct response to "something went wrong" is to renew the lease (maybe there are more details you want to add?).  Anyway, if nothing else helps have a look at this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5121/5538 I used that for a long time when what the problem turned out to be was a wonky relationship between the driver and the adapter -- or something.  Anyway, no such problems w/ a different adapter, but that script did keep things running fine before that.

Comment: You have given absolutely no information, so any answer is speculative. List any config files you have changed. The standard setup on Raspbian should work. You seem to be running the GUI, but still post output of `ifconfig`.