# Using a Pi as Access Point, using TWO LTE connections

Tags: networking

The bandwidth of my DSL is too low to share voice + image at the same time.
I have a dedicated 4G/LTE line for internet access.
Unfortunately, area is crowdy and thus pylon bandwidth is shared between local users.
Fine, except when I need to videocall with a class.

My idea is to create an access point that would connect to the net via my dedicated 4G + my main subscription (4G) via tethering both phones, connected to the pi via usb

The closest article I found is

[How does the RPi 3 handle simultaneous LAN and WiFi connections](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58541/how-does-the-rpi-3-handle-simultaneous-lan-and-wifi-connections?r=SearchResults&s=1|53.9111)

which is close to the target but not adapted to my network knowledge. I want to bundle both connections to increase bandwidth.

How could I split the applicative network connections over the two 4G network connections ?

Thank you

Comment: The link you have referenced is asking for a backup or fail over configuration. Do you also want this? Or do you want to split communication, voice through one connection, image trough the other? Or do you want to bundle both connections to increase bandwidth?

Comment: Hello Ingo, I want to bundle both connections to increase bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

You want to bundle two connections to increase bandwidth. In general bundling connections is done with **bonding**. This has different [Network Bonding Modes](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-are-the-network-bonding-modes-in-centos-rhel/). For your use case the default mode 0 (Round-robin) is appropriate. Unfortunately I haven't a setup available for mode 0. But for using mode 1, Active Backup, I have an example at [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover). This is not what you want but my suggestion is to setup this first to become familiar with the bonding driver and then reconfigure it to use Round-robin (mode 0).