# Raspberry PI random connection interruptions

Tags: python, wifi, ssh

i am running a raspberry pi B+ headless and losing network connection irregulary.
I am living with that since a few years, but now want to fix the problem.
What would be a good approach to find out the reason?

**Problem**

- ssh connection to PI not possible sometimes (today failing nearly constantly, otherwise every few days)
- Active ssh connection aborted
- PI cannot get internet data (pinging google fails)

**Setup**

- Raspberry PI B+
- WIFI USB Adapter EDIMAX EW 7811Un
- My own app (digital picture frame) is running on python 3 and QT5.7

**My countermeasures so far**

- self implemented software wachdog that checks some connection parameters and reboots if necessary (i would say works in 95% of the cases)
- Auto PowerOff deactivated for the Wifi adapter by setting *rtw_power_mgnt=0* and *rtw_enusbss=0* in */etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf*

**Comments**

- My WIFI connection at home sometimes gets interrupted as well. But far less often than the connection to the PI fails
- I know that similar questions have been asked before, but i was not able to adapt them to my specific problem, sorry.

Thanks for any directions

Ben

Comment: *"checks some connection parameters and reboots if necessary"* -> It can never be necessary to reboot just to fix a basic connection issue (with the exception of some driver bugs, but as far as I've noticed this is not a problem on the Pi using the built-in interfaces, and I believe 8192cu is also fine).  Put another way: You need to determine how to start, stop, and restart networking connectivity properly.  On current Rasbpian  this should be as simple as `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd`, but YMMV.

Comment: @goldilocks: Thanks for the "hdcpcd restart command", i didn't know it and will try it. 1) Now, how would i detect, that the connection is broke and i should restart it? 2) How could i now find out the reason, so i can fix it and don't need a restart at all?

Comment: [Here's some suggestions about using `ping` by me from a few years ago](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5121/5538).  It's not a perfect technique (it is not very responsive as it means it can be offline for a minute depending on what you set the timings to, which is not such a big deal for a headless Pi on the LAN, but irritating if it is a laptop, etc).  Currently I'm using dhcpcd hooks instead (see `man dhcpcd-run-hooks`), but that is probably a bit too technical.

Comment: BTW, if you don't shell script but are comfortable coding in python or something, use that instead as shell has a lot of gotchas, which is a PITA when the context is a background thing that only does important things on occasion (not a good learning context).  That said, the verbatim script from that answer is not too brittle, but it does use a non-standard form of networking (`dhclient` + `wpa_supplicant`, no corresponding system service) which you would probably want to replace with the current Raspbian norm (`systemctl ____ dhcpcd`).

Comment: How did you verify that the problem is  definitely the RasPi and not your home router, or any other component?

Comment: @Ingo: that's exactly the most important question I have. How can I find out what's the reason? Log files etc. maybe

Comment: Any ideas which log file contains useful information?

Comment: There are some log files or a journal but it depends on the operating system. What do you use? Raspbian Buster? Please add a tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts :-

- This post shows a couple of possibilities. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=129021 MrEngman I gather wrote a helpful installer script for the Edmix range of Wifis.  Research a bit more yourself before trying these perhaps.

  1) Remove ifplugd

  ```
  apt-get purge ifplugd
  ```

  2) Disable any conflicting drivers, read in more detail before doing anything, but e.g.

  ```
  blacklist rtl8192cu
  blacklist rtl8xxxu.conf
  ```
- Have you tried updating your raspbian/kernel/firmware?  It might help fix the situation. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```
- It may be possible that your power supply may be a bit too weak/unreliable to drive the USB wifi.
- I remember my EDIMAX clone wifi being quite cheap and a pain to setup and use.  Buying a different brand may help, though I notice the Pi brand can have this problem too.
- Treat yourself to a newer Pi with built-in Wifi ;)

Good luck!